# Are swift higher order functions sync or async ? are they thread safe or not?

Tags: swift

Are swift higher order functions like map, reduce, filter, sort : synchronous or asynchronous ?
and are higher order functions are thread safe or not ? if not then how can we make them thread safe ? By implementing them inside serial queue ?

Comment: Therre are no asynchronous functions in the Swift Standard Library, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Nothing's thread safe unless it specifically claims to be thread safe. Normally functions aren't thread safe, it's the data structures they manipulate that need to be. Unless you use Grand Central Dispatch everything is synchronous.

Answer (score 3):

> Are swift higher order functions like map, reduce, filter, sort ?

Synchronous

> Thread safe

No , it's your job to use in a non-mixed way otherwise embed the operation in a serial queue ( main queue is serial)

Comment: You shouldn't use the main queue for long running tasks though, since it's blocking the UI. Use a dedicated serial queue for background processing, then dispatch the result to the main queue when it needs to be displayed on the UI (if ever).

Comment: actually this depends on how complex is the operation if it's usual like we do then to use in main queue otherwise creating a serial queue is the only other option and to guarantee thread safety also

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a function or a block to another function, notice the type of the parameter: it can be `@escaping` or `@nonescaping` (the latter is the default and is usually omitted from the definiteion).

**Non-escaping** blocks will definitely be called on the same thread in a synchronous manner. For example, all list manipulation higher order functions (map, filter, etc) are non-escaping. In fact some of these functions can be inlined and optimized by the compiler to not have any function calls at all.

**Escaping** blocks are a bit different. If you design a higher order function yourself and you happen to store the block in a variable to be called later, the compiler will force you to declare it as `@escaping`. These blocks are allowed to be called much later and from any thread.

When dealing with system or API calls you need to check the documentation. For example the documentation on `AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for:completionHandler:)` states the callback can be called on arbitrary thread and therefore you are responsible for ensuring your UI code is executed on the main thread. You typically do it this way:

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: { (granted) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Execute UI code here
    }
})
```

Another example is the `URLSessionTask` family of classes that typically deliver the results of a network operation via an async callback on a non-main thread. You can take advantage of the fact that you are on a different thread, or you could "return" to the main one like in the example above.

All in all, it's up to the designer of the higher order function, so a short answer is: if it's an escaping parameter then check the documentation.